# Configure power button to shutdown on Debian

Tags: shutdown

I use Debian and I want my power button to shutdown the PC. Currently it sleeps, when I press it.

Is there any command for it to make it shutdown?

Comment: Some while ago I created this handy script: https://github.com/stackcoder/doublepress
It can prevent accidental shutdowns by requiring double pressing the power button. It also allows switching between standby and poweroff, or triggers your custom action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn-acpi-support` leads to `/etc/acpi/powerbtn-acpi-support.sh`, which in turns calls for `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`.  I've not tested, but you may try to create this file and fill it with something like

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
```

Note that in principle it won't exit your session cleanly, though, so depending on the desktop environment / window manager you use you may want to improve it to handle things more cleanly (e.g. adding `gnome-session-save --kill` before if you use gnome).

The best way to go would probably be to google search for other users `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` scripts.

#### Update

`/etc/acpi` is not used anymore (probably after Debian Wheezy), see `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, more info in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1360765).

Answer (score 2):

**For modern Debian versions with systemd (>=Debian 8.0 Jessie)**

Make sure you have acpid installed:

```
apt-get -y install acpid
```

and edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to uncomment:

```
HandlePowerKey=poweroff
```

See [systemd logind.conf man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#) for more options.

**For older Debian releases (<=Debian 7)**

See [Skippy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97581/73271)

---

Credits: [Michls Tech Blog](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/debian-shutdown-when-pressing-power-button/)