# Configure power button to shutdown on Debian/Mac Mini G4

Tags: shutdown, acpi, powerpc

I use Debian/PPC on an old Mac Mini G4, it currently serve as a DLNA server (UPnP), no mouse or keyboard plugged.

I would like that my power button also serves to shutdown the box. Currently it does nothing, on recent x86 I would have used ACPI as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97565/configure-power-button-to-shutdown-on-debian).

However ACPI does not seems to be available from my G4 box (see for example [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1513862) or [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1723290)), only `pbbuttonsd` is available, see [link](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/pbbuttonsd.html).

I could not find whether or not any event (APM type?) is sent when pressing the power button. I know that I can hold the power button for 4s then the machine halt, but I would prefer a clean shutdown. As a last resort I could plug in a keyboard but I am looking for a solution without mouse or keyboard.

How would one do that ?

EDIT: Using web.archive.org I was able to read: http://web.archive.org/web/20110317165103/http://blog.blinker.net/2010/06/20/mac-mini-g4-homeserver-with-ubuntu-linux-10-04-wpa2/

I used the solution suggested:

> I got this working on my G4 Quicksilver with Ubuntu by installing
>   pbbuttonsd.
>
> I had to modify /etc/pbbuttonsd.conf and change this line:
>
> OnAC_KeyAction = none
>
> to:
>
> OnAC_KeyAction = shutdown
>
> I ran /etc/init.d/pbbuttonsd restart to restart the daemon, and then
>   the power button worked to trigger a clean shutdown.

But this did not work for me, maybe there is a difference in between PowerBook and Mac Mini G4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging into the source code, I was able to suggest the following patch on the pbbuttons mailing list, as seen [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pbbuttons/mailman/message/33204845/).

Turns out the code would only consider a power button press event in case:

```
if (n == 6 && ((intr[1] >> 3) & 1) != PBpressed) {
```

while the comment just above explains that:

```
/* n = 2 && intr[1] = 0x0c = %01100 power button on mac-mini */
```

so I simply changed it to:

```
if (n == 2 && intr[1] == 0x0c ) {
```

Now I can properly configure the `OnAC_KeyAction` to shutdown ! No need for a keyboard for a simple action like this now !

Comment: Thanks for the good work. Upvoting you (so you get a few extra reputation points for your care of the PowerPC platform)!

Comment: @rbrito thanks ! I'll even get back my own bounty points which I previously lost :)